# Edit visibility of a cell in GridView based on a value in the row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind

I'm trying to set a my delete button visibility to true when the value of the last cell in row is equal to the session value which is the userID

**Girdview UPDATED:**

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="attachID" HeaderText="Attachment ID" SortExpression="atID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidcol" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidcol"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="attachmentTitle" HeaderText="Attachment Title" SortExpression="attachmentTitle" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="attachmentType" HeaderText="Attachment Type" SortExpression="attachmentType" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="attachmentDescription" HeaderText="Attachment Description" SortExpression="attachmentDescription" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="attachmentDate" HeaderText="Attachment Date" SortExpression="attachmentDate" />
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="download"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("attachmentFile") %>'><img src="CSS/images/download.png" alt="Download File" /></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("userID") %>' CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/CSS/images/delete_page.png" Text="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

I'm trying to set the Delete button property visibile if the `userID` machates the `session["username"]`

I'm not sure this is the right way or not.

**Code-Behind UPDATED:**

```
String searchValue = "" + Session["username"];

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        // Only look in data rows
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow ||
            row.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow)
        {
            // Find the delete button by ID
            ImageButton theDeleteButton = row.FindControl("ImageButton1") as ImageButton;

            // Verify the button was found before we try to use it
            if (theDeleteButton != null)
            {
                if (theDeleteButton.CommandArgument != searchValue)
                {
                    // Make the button invisible
                    theDeleteButton.Visible = false;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

How can i make it happen ?

thanks in advance!

**The Code has been Updated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a `TemplateField` for the delete button with a `CommandName` attribute (similar to what you are doing with the download link button) rather than a `CommandField`, because it will make your code for hiding the delete button cleaner, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" CommandName="delete"  
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' Text="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code-behind:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    // Only look in data rows
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || 
        row.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow)
    {
        // Find the delete button by ID
        Button theDeleteButton = row.FindControl("ButtonDelete") as Button;

        // Verify the button was found before we try to use it
        if(theDeleteButton != null)
        {
            // Make the button invisible
            theDeleteButton.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The `as` operator will return `null` if the attempted cast cannot be completed successfully; hence the check for `null` against `theDeleteButton` variable.

Comment: well how should i check the `userID` value against `Session["username"]` ? becasue i want the delete button hidden when the value doesn't match!

Comment: @pouria - same thing, make `userID` a `TemplateField` rather than `BoundField` so you can get rid of that error prone `row.Cells[x]` syntax. `FindControl` is not perfect, but it is not dependent upon the order of the columns in the grid.

Comment: thanks! as you showed in your example i used `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'`!